# How to debug 500 error on remove in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I am getting a 500 error on the code below

```
/**
 * @Operation(
 *     tags={"User"},
 *     summary="Remove account",
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response="200",
 *         description="Returned when successful"
 *     )
 * )
 * @Rest\Put("/removeAccount")
 * @return JsonResponse
 * @throws \Exception If something critical happened.
 */
public function removeAccount()
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->remove($user);

    $em->flush();

    return JsonResponse::create([
        'code' => JsonResponse::HTTP_OK,
        'message' => 'Account has been deleted',
    ]);
}
```

There is nothing in the prod.log/dev.log or php_errors.log

Any ideas on how I can debug this?

Comment: what about apache/nginx log? Also, make sure to log out user.

Comment: You are letting a logged in user to self-delete their own account? Doesn't seem like the greatest idea. A prime spot for a soft-delete and logout.

Answer (score 1):

You should logout the user by removing it from the token_storage:

```
/**
 * @Operation(
 *     tags={"User"},
 *     summary="Remove account",
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response="200",
 *         description="Returned when successful"
 *     )
 * )
 * @Rest\Put("/removeAccount")
 * @return JsonResponse
 * @throws \Exception If something critical happened.
 */
public function removeAccount()
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->remove($user);

    $em->flush();

    return JsonResponse::create([
        'code' => JsonResponse::HTTP_OK,
        'message' => 'Account has been deleted',
    ]);
}
```